# XSLT Attribute Matching With Namespaces

Tags: xslt, attributes, namespaces, matching

I can not find a good explanation for why the second example here works but the first does not:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xsd"
    version="2.0">

  <xsl:template match="/">

    <xsl:value-of select="/wsdl:definitions/wsdl:message[@name = $messageName]"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="/wsdl:definitions/wsdl:message/@name[. = $messageName]"/>

  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The context is finding a specific named message in a WSDL document. I suspect it has something to do with namespacing just about everything that trips me up badly with XSLT is but I do not understand why?

could someone shine a light on this for me I don't like experimenting to get a solution as it does not lead to understanding.

the relevent sections of the WSDL are:

```
<definitions xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">

   <message name="retrieveCustomerYtdResponse">
      <part name="parameter"/>
   </message>
   <message name="retrieveCustomerYtdRequest"/>

</definitions>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no any issue about namespaces. Both expressions are correct and produce the expected result.

Assuming (at least) a context template for the instructions, with the first instruction you are trying to print the text nodes descendant of **wsdl:message** with given **@name**. Nothing will be printed out as no text inside that element.

The second instruction will print the value of **@name**. That's correct.

Comment: Yes you are absolutely right thanks for the explanation. The first expression is indeed returning the text nodes and that was the knowledge I was missing. If I now understand correctly /wsdl:definitions/wsdl:message[@name = $messageName]/@name would have given me what I wanted in this case.

Comment: Yes. That's correct. Please make sure to **[accept the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)** if you think your question is solved.

Comment: Personally, I prefer the XPath expression where **@name** is repeated once only.